# GoogleCharts + MySQL/json

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json, google-visualization

I have been struggling to get this working for few days now. What I want is to create column/barchart with googlecharts. And generate that dynamically from my database.

**My query:**

```
SELECT gs.league as league
             , (Select Count(*) From gamestats WHERE season=gs.season AND league=gs.league AND event=1) as one
             , (Select Count(*) From gamestats WHERE season=gs.season AND league=gs.league AND event=2) as two
             , (Select Count(*) From gamestats WHERE season=gs.season AND league=gs.league AND event=3) as three
             , (Select Count(*) From gamestats WHERE season=gs.season AND league=gs.league AND event=4) as four
             , (Select Count(*) From gamestats WHERE season=gs.season AND league=gs.league AND event=5) as five
             , (Select Count(*) From gamestats WHERE season=gs.season AND league=gs.league AND event=6) as six
           FROM gamestats gs WHERE gs.season=2013 AND gs.league < 3 GROUP by gs.league
```

If i just try to json_encode($result) it gives me wrong kind of format of json. This is what I get now:

```
[{"league":"2","one":"9","two":"3","three":"9","four":"2","five":"8","six":"12"},{"league":"4","one":"1","two":"0","three":"0","four":"1","five":"1","six":"2"}]
```

That doesn't generate anything. In GoogleChart examples json is like this:

```
{
"cols": [
  {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
    {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
  ],
  "rows": [
    {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Olives","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Zucchini","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Pepperoni","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]}
  ]
}
```

How can I get that kind of json format from my query? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled with this too a while ago. Here's how I fixed it, I think you will understand.

```
$data = $this->stats_model->get_flights_data(); // this is the model

$label = array();

array_push($label, array("id" => "", "label" => "Airline", "pattern" => "", "type" => "string"));
array_push($label, array("id" => "", "label" => "Amount", "pattern" => "", "type" => "number"));

$rows = array();
foreach($data as $result) {
    array_push($rows, array("c" => array(array("v" => $result['airline'], "f" => null), array("v" => (int)$result['amount'], "f" => null ))));
}

$cols = array("cols" => $label, "rows" => $rows);
echo json_encode($cols);
```

And this is my model:

```
$query = "SELECT count(flight_number) AS `amount`, airline from flights_database WHERE flight_date = CURDATE() AND airline != '' GROUP by airline HAVING count(flight_number)>0 ORDER by count(flight_number) DESC, airline DESC LIMIT 10";

$q = $this->db->query($query);
$data = $q->result_array();

return $data;
```

Hope this gives you some insight!

Comment: Wow thanks! Now I can get the charts to show up. But having some new issues now.. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62375224/chart.png <-  Left values 1-6 are for League and the right ones for Division1. How can I get those right ones to say Division1 and color those bars red? And if possible, how I can put same values from both league/division1 next to each other or even stacked? Thanks again! :)

Comment: You need to create another label, and also add another array like `array("v" => (int)$result['amount'], "f" => null )` to the end of the array_push

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, stupid me.. Thanks again! All working correctly now :)